# Filtering array by date

Tags: php, sorting, datetime, filter, format

I have an array filled with items. Every item has a StartDate with the format `d/m/Y H:i:s`.

I want to order the array items, from earliest to last.

I already tried doing

```
$client = [ [ 'LessonId' => 1, 'StartTime' => '20/11/2022 10:30:00', 'EndTime' => '20/11/2022 11:30:00', 'LessonName' => 'Dance', ], [ 'LessonId' => 2, 'StartTime' => '20/11/2022 09:30:00', 'EndTime' => '20/11/2022 10:30:00', 'LessonName' => 'Dance', ], ];

usort($client, function ($a, $b) {
    $pos_a = strtotime(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $a['StartTime']));
    $pos_b = strtotime(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $b['StartTime']));
    return $pos_a <=> $pos_b;
});
```

Sadly it's not working since the array is still in it's old order. I'm not even sure if I still need `strtotime()` since I already tell php which date format the fields are.

Comment: It's unclear to me what your array looks like. Please provide a small example as PHP code so that your problem can be reproduced.

Comment: @jspit $sportivityClient = [
    [
        'LessonId' => 1,
        'StartTime' => '20/11/2022 10:30:00',
        'EndTime' => '20/11/2022 11:30:00',
        'LessonName' => 'Dance',
    ],
    [
        'LessonId' => 2,
        'StartTime' => '20/11/2022 09:30:00',
        'EndTime' => '20/11/2022 10:30:00',
        'LessonName' => 'Dance',
    ],
]; as you can see the second element, begins earlier. But I managed to fix it, apparently, a value returned false which made the sorting break

Comment: Your example data should already contain all relevant values and be added to your question. Here, for example, values with NULL.

Comment: Yeah it'll help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first it didn't work because one or more values returned false.
Later after figuring that out, I managed to fix it by converting the dates to a time stamp. and doing:

```
usort($arrayToSort , function ($a, $b) {
        if($a['startTime'] == null && $b['startTime'] == null) return 0;
        if($a['startTime'] == null) return 1; //1 -> "a is greater than b"
        if($b['startTime'] == null) return -1; //-1 -> "a is less than b"
        
        return $a['startTime'] <=> $b['startTime'];
    });
```

Comment: Your solution is wrong. Make a test with the values 'StartTime' => '22/11/2022 10:30:00', and 'StartTime' => '20/12/2022 09:30:00'.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong, when I dump the data, everything is shown in the right order.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/8So1q A date in the format d/m/Y cannot be sorted as a string.